# Give an example of a group with elements x and y such that $(xy)^{-1}\neq x^{-1}y^{-1}$

Tags: group-theory

> Give an example of a group with elements x and y such that $(xy)^{-1}\neq  x^{-1}y^{-1}$

Let G be a group and let $x,y \in G $

By definition of groups,
 $xy\in G, (xy)^{-1}\in G $ so that $y^{-1}x^{-1}\in G$

So, $(xy)^{-1}=y^{-1}x^{-1}=x^{-1}y^{-1} \iff G$ is abelian

thus, if I choose a group $G$ which is not abelian, then I am done.

Is this correct?

Comment: $G=S_3$, $x=\tau$ (order $2$), $y=\gamma$ (order $3$) is sort of the *minimal example*. Correct.

Comment: Indeed, take one element as a transposition and the other as a nontrivial cycle.

Comment: You are correct that you need to choose a group which is not abelian.  However, even in a nonabelian group, you may coincidentally find two elements $x$ and $y$ such that $(xy)^{-1}=x^{-1}y^{-1}$.  As you pointed out, though, this can't be true *for all* $x$ and $y$ in a nonabelian group, so you should be able to find elements for which the equation is false.

Comment: Yes, and to show it's non-Abelian all you need is two elements with $xy\ne yx$,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your idea is exactly right. Any non-Abelian group will get the job done. Note that, indeed, the best we can hope for is to find a group $G$ such that *there exist* two elements $x,y\in G$ for which 
$$xy\ne yx\iff (xy)^{-1}\ne x^{-1}y^{-1}.$$
Because, given any group $G$, we have that taking $y=e$ and $x\in G$ arbitrary, $xe=x=ex$, so that $(xe)^{-1}=x^{-1}=x^{-1}e=x^{-1}e^{-1}$.

Comment: I didnt take into account the identity element, so for any group we actually have $xe=ex\qquad$    and $  \quad  (xe)^{-1}=x^{-1}e^{-1} \qquad \qquad$  for all x in the group. So I can't give an example of such group?

Comment: You can, because any noncommutative group contains _a pair_ of elements that do not commute, and that is what you are looking for. The point is that no group can be constructed such that _no pair_ of elements commutes.

Answer (score 1):

If you take $x=(12)$ and $y=(13)$ in $S_3$. As $x=x^{-1}$ and $y=y^{-1}$.

Then $y^{-1}x^{-1}=(13)(12)$. But $xyx^{-1}y^{-1}=(12)(13)(12)(13)=(132)(132)=(123)\neq e$.